# Android Raw XML file inserts comments

Tags: android, xml

I have a method that copies an XML file from `/res/raw/` into local storage. However, the file it ends up copying has an additional comment generated that isn't in the original XML file:

```
<!-- From: file:/C:/Users/William/Documents/Projects/Home/KanjiFixProject/KanjiFix/src/main/res/raw/fallback_fonts.xml -->
```

It appears to give the location of where the file existed when I compiled the project. [See here for the full file text.](https://gist.github.com/ascendedguard/6801971)

**What is causing this text to appear, and how can I prevent it?** The following is the method I use to copy the file from `/res/raw/` onto disk:

```
private void copyRawResourceToFile(int resource, File outputFile) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(resource);
    FileOutputStream output = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read = 0;
    try {
        output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        while ((read = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        output.flush();
    }
    finally {
        stream.close();

        if (output != null) {
            output.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tested this code and the file was copied successfully just like the original file, without additional comment. Maybe there is an app installed that intercepts file copy and add the comment? Though I'm not sure if there is such app...

Comment: Just to be more complete, I'm using Android Studio 0.2.10 and I'm testing on Android 4.3 Galaxy Nexus with Stock ROM. I'm guessing it might be a quirk with Android Studio? My full source is open source, and that line definitely isn't there: https://github.com/ascendedguard/android-kanji-fix/blob/master/KanjiFix/src/main/res/raw/fallback_fonts.xml

Comment: This is happening to me, too, when compiling the app (regardless of debug mode, or release mode) from the command line using the Gradle build system.

Comment: Looks like it relates to resource merging that the new build system does. Every XML file in build/res/ has a comment like that added. I can understand why it happens, but it would be nice if there was a way to turn if off for raw XML files. Or the build system should remove the comments after resource merging is complete.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr Agreed. Let me know if you do find a way to disable this.

Comment: @WillEddins I posted on the Android dev tools mailing list about this. It should hopefully get fixed (as raw files shouldn't be altered): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/4a0pg3Sb9Sk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of Android Studio (v0.8.14 as of this post) have since fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a way to programatically prevent the stream from inserting that value, why don't you make use of BufferReader and readLine by line before sending to the OutputStream, giving you the chance to validate that the line do not start with "<-- From: file:", otherway just ignore that line.

This would do the trick but i don't know if is actually the best approach since there might be a way to programatically skip that extraline when reading it...

Hope this Helps...

Regards!